# SWIFT: Mobile Application connect to Amazon Web Service

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there any way to connect my iOS application to Amazon Web Services? Specially on S3 or RDS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. 
https://aws.amazon.com/s3/getting-started/
What have you done yourself?
Amazon has excellent descriptions and 'how-to's'